# remove polygon fillColor and strokeColor after zoom

Tags: xml, google-maps-api-3, kml, polygons, stroke

When you zoom to some polygon I would like to remove (fillColor, stokeColor) that polygon from map.

Here is sample:
http://mini.hr/stanonline/test2.php

Here is method for zooming to selected polygon:

```
function kmlShowPlacemark(pm) {
  if(geoXmlDoc.placemarks[pm].polygon){
  map.fitBounds(geoXmlDoc.placemarks[pm].polygon.bounds);}
```

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

geoXmlDoc.placemarks[pm].polygon is a [Google Maps API v3 Polygon](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Polygon), to change its properties you can call the setOptions function on it with the updated fillColor and strokeColor.  You can't "remove" fillColor and strokeColor, but you can change them and change the fillOpacity and strokeWeight to make them not visible.

[Developers Guide description of Polygons](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#Polygons)

This will change the first polygon (the first "Placemark") to red with a blue border 5 pixels wide:

```
geoXmlDoc.placemarks[0].polygon.setOptions({
      fillColor:"#FF0000",    // red
      fillOpacity:0.9,
      strokeColor:"#0000FF",  // blue
      strokeWeight:5          // pixels
});
```

this will make that same polygon fully transparent (opacity 0.001), with no border:

```
geoXmlDoc.placemarks[0].polygon.setOptions({
      fillColor:"#000000",
      fillOpacity:0.001,
      strokeColor:"#000000",
      strokeWeight:0
});
```

If you want to remove that polygon from the map, call setMap(null) on it.

Comment: tnx a lot, i do like that:
`for (var i=0;i<geoXmlDoc.placemarks.length;i++) {
     var placemark = geoXmlDoc.placemarks[i];
     if (i == pm) {
       if (placemark.polygon) placemark.polygon.setMap(null);
     } else {
       if (placemark.polygon) placemark.polygon.setMap(map);
     }`